# Static Class and Private Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, static

I am not able to understand this. I tried doing a small example in VS2010 as below.

"Creating a static class is therefore much the same as creating a class that contains only static members and a private constructor"

Does this statement means a class with private constructor and one or more static methods like below is static class ? I know we call a class static only when static keyword is mentioned in class.

Also, we cannot inherit the below class and also we can't instantiate this class right ?

```
public class Base
{
    private Base() { Console.WriteLine(" I am from normal Base constructor"); }
    static void NewMethod() { Console.WriteLine("Hey I am from Static Base"); }
    public void New() { } 
}
```

Comment: *Only static members* is not the same thing as *one or more static methods*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What it means is that:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Bar() { }
}
```

is essentially the same as

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo() { }
    public static void Bar() { }
}
```

because if the class only has a private constructor, it cannot be instantiated outside the class.

Comment: Thank you for the quick example, its easy to understand :) so it means 1) we cannot inherit the class also right ? I mean the class with private constructor. 2) And also, can this class with private constructor have many static methods ? 3) Whats the term you use to call such a class with private constructor ? Its again Static class you say ? 4) Someone above told that, "Contains only static members is not the same thing as one or more static methods". Hows this possible ? I am not able to understand the difference.

Comment: 1) Yes, you cannot inherit from a class which only has a private constructor. 2) Yes, as far as I know there is no limit to the number of methods a class can declare although you should ensure that the class does not start doing to much (read up on Single Responsibility Principle) 3) It's essentially "sealed" because if it only contains private constructors it cannot be inherited from or instantiated. 4) what they mean is that a class can have instance and static methods, in this case you cannot have a static class since it cannot contain instance methods.

Comment: Correct, that what is meant. It's not exactly the same, of course. For example, in the second case it will be allowed to say `Foo variable = null;`, or define a method `void M(Foo foo) { }`. Also, if you don't mark it as `sealed`, one can use generic constraints like `where T : Foo`.

Comment: A non-sealed class all of whose instance constructors are `private`, can be inherited from _only_ by classes nested withing itself. In the above example, `Foo` contains no nested types. Also, the `private` constructors can be used to instantiate the class from _inside_ the class, but the above `Foo` contains no `new` object expressions.

Comment: @TrevorPilley: Thank you so much, that aptly answer all my questions in the way that I can chew :). I have one more question, its silly though. Whats the difference between having a method explicitly saying sealed and having a method with private constructor (Leaving behind the advantage of private constructors or static method)

Answer (score 13):

> Creating a static class is therefore much the same as creating a class that contains only static members and a private constructor

This statement is attempting to get across the right idea but failing to do so. A static class is *not* like a class with only static members and a private constructor. Here's a class with static members and private constructor:

```
class X
{
    private X() {}
    public static X Y() { return new X(); }
}
```

But that's not at all like a static class! The author of that statement seems to think that having a private constructor prevents you from making instances, but of course it does not.

A more accurate statement would be:

> Creating a static class is much like creating a class that is both abstract and sealed, and contains no instance members.

And in fact, when the C# compiler generates the code for a static class, that's precisely what it does: it marks the class as both abstract (so it cannot be instantiated directly) and sealed (so that it cannot be extended).

I note that it is not legal for you to declare a class both abstract and sealed yourself; the only way to do so in C# is to make a static class.

I will bring the misleading sentence to the attention of the MSDN documentation managers. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hi Eric Lippert, thank you so much for taking time to write to me and make me understand. I know, I was a bit uncomfortable to convey what I thought, you got it very correct. Thank you so much again. And one thing that surprised me is, before seeing your statement "I note that it is not legal for you to declare a class both abstract and sealed yourself; the only way to do so in C# is to make a static class.", when I read until the line above this statement, I quickly went to VS and did abstract and sealed and got error and when I was about to write to you back, but I found you have addressed

Comment: So I am very happy that you addressed and cleared my every doubt on this. :) Thank you so much. Cheers

Comment: @Divine: You are very welcome. I have spoken with the documentation manager and he will look into updating that page to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Interesting. Never known this subtle difference; But that's also because I avoid static as much as possible. It's contradictory to OOP

Comment: @Jowen: Avoiding a language feature because you find it "contrary to OOP" seems unfortunate; it's a useful feature. OOP is goodness because that style of programming lowers the costs of writing software in large teams, not because it is blessed by the gods of programming. The important thing is that your programs be correct, understandable, maintainable, and solve a real customer problem, not that they be beautiful examples of OOP.

Comment: @EricLippert: 'Avoiding' is a big word. Of course there are very good/valid usages of static, that's why I added 'as much as possible' :) However, my experiences are that it's being overused, in places where it shouldn't. In my attempt to educate/convince other programmers I make bold statements... which lead to healthy discussions!

Answer (score 4):

> "Does this statement mean a class with private constructor and one or
>   more static methods like below is a static class?"

The answer is No, and one difference is explained in exactly the next sentence after the one you are citing from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> The advantage of using a static class is that the compiler can check
>   to make sure that no instance members are accidentally added.

---

It means that you will get a compiler error in `Class2` shown below.

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class1() { }
    public static void Method() { }
    private string member; // valid, but pointless
}

public static class Class2
{
    public static void Method() { }
    private string member; // error CS0708
}
```

---

More important, although `Class1` has a private constructor, it may still be instantiated:

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class1() { }

    private static Class1 instance = new Class1();

    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
}
```

A static class on the other hand, may never be instantiated.

Comment: Hi Clemens, thank you so much for the point that the class can still be instantiated when it has private constructor. So this is something they call it as Singleton ? Correct ?

Comment: Could you please tell me a real time example of when this kind of instantiation of a class with private constructor happens ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how `Class1` would implement the singleton pattern. You would access the singleton instance by the static `Class1.Instance` property.

Comment: Thank you Clemens, that helps me. Can you please tell me how to access a public property in a class with private constructor like above. Example,  public class Class1
        {
            private Class1() { }

            private static Class1 instance = new Class1();

            public static Class1 Instance
            {
                get { return instance; }
            }

            public string Name;
        }

Comment: How should I access the property Name ? although I declared it as public, since its not inheritable, how should I access it outside this class

Comment: `var name = Class1.Instance.Name;`. Note that what you declared is not a property, but a public field.

Comment: Thank you so much Clemens, its coming without error :) I am happy :) Cheers

Comment: Clemens, just noticed you said, its a private field but not property. I agree with you, however, with C#3.0, we put property without get and set accessor right ? So its not a property ? Could you please tell me how to differentiate ?

Comment: With get or set accessors it's a property, without it's a field. Perhaps you mean [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), which would be written `public string Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: Clemens, that's very correct, sorry got confused, thank you so much for your time and clearing my all doubts :) I appreciate it greatly. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can not inherit as there is no public constructor, only a private constructor exists. For the same reason you can not create an instance.

Within the scope of this question, they can be seen as the same. Can you call it a static class; I think officially you do not since it is not marked as `static` in the class definition. But in the perspective of functionality you may call it `static`.

Comment: Of course, it's not _really_ `static`. You can still do `var list = new List<Base>();` or `var array = new Base[100];` for example. See other examples in my comments to other questions.

Answer (score 0):

With your example, the only way the `New()` method can be called is if you add another method to return a `Base` instance since `Base` can't be instantiated by another class. Not having that extra method makes it functionally the same as a static class.

Comment: Though the compiler doesn't know that. It will still allow stuff like `Base variable = null;`, `var list = new List<Base>();`, `public Base Method(Base parameter) { return null; }`, generic constraints of the form `where T : Base`, and lots of other constructions that are meaningless and disallowed for truely `static` classes. (And of course via reflection you can instantiate `Base` and run the private constructor if you like; this cannot happen with a `static` type since it's abstract as seen from the Framework.)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the statement:

> Creating a static class is therefore much the same as creating a class
>   that contains only static members and a private constructor

What it is trying to say is that you can not create an instance of a static class.

The way to create a static class is to use the **static** keyword.  All members in the class must also be static.

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
      static MyStaticClass() { /* Constructor.  Optional. */ }
      public static void MyMethod() { ... }
      public static int MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Note again, you can not create an instance of this class.  The following call will not compile:

```
new MyStaticClass();
```

Comment: Hi Josh, I got that statement from MSDN: Please follow  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A static class can never be instantiated, participate in inheritance, or use interfaces. But a class, even with a private constructor can still inherit, where a static class cannot. And a class with a private constructor can still instantiate an instance of itself. A static cannot do that. So NO they are not the same.

I do not understand why Microsoft at times still doesn't understand what it created, because they are the ones that wrote that description (as Eric Lippert mentioned)?

The other confusion is whether a Static Constructor is Private or Public? That would help explain behavior because like the default public constructor in every class, there is also a default constructor for every static class. To me that implies the static constructor would be public, but it is not. It cannot be accessed or called, and can be overwritten.

Because the static class is translated when compiled into an abstract class that's sealed, that suggests its static constructor really is just another default public class constructor without parameters that can be called only once. I could be wrong. But if that's the case, the whole private constructor explanation makes no sense.